# Finding the area contained within a section.

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm doing analysis on some land in Blaine County, Oklahoma. I have a shapefile with the perimeter coordinates for all sections in Blaine and many different references to location. A few examples include:

```
S06 T13N R11W SE NW
S10 T16N R12W E2 NW
S34 T15N R11W SE NW L8
```

The first three values in these location references represent the section, township, range, and region and the remaining values are in a quad-tree notation that represents some plot on the section. For example, the first one reads: "the southeast corner of the northeast corner of section 6 of township 13N of range 11W" and the second one reads: "the eastern half of the northwestern corner of section 10 of township 16 of range 12W." The third reads: "the northwest corner of the southeast corner of section 34 in township 15N in range 11W." Note that the configuration of lots on the land is unknown (as far as I know) so we discard the last value.

I'm wondering if there is some pre-built method that can give me the approximate location that is being described by these entries. The inputs to the method would be some representation of the information provided in the entries excluding the section/township/range metadata and the coordinate perimeter of the section that is described by the section/township/range. It's definitely possible to solve this problem, but I don't want to bother with rotating the sections, creating a parser for the notation described, and coding all the geometric logic by hand, so I'm looking for something easier.

Any ideas?